# Add space between margin and footnote marker

Tags: footnotes, indentation, footmisc

Consider the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1em}

\begin{document}
Content.\footnote{Footnote}
\end{document}
```

I want to add a small space (say, 1 em) between the margin and the footnote marker while leaving everything else unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

`\footnotemargin` has a different meaning when using `hang`. From the [`footmisc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/footmisc.pdf) (section **1.11 Option `hang`**, p 4):

> This option sets the footnote mark flush with the margin, and makes the body
>   of the footnote hang at an indentation of `\footnotemargin` (if that is a positive
>   distance), or the width of the marker (if `\footnotemargin <= 0`). The option code
>   itself leaves `\footnotemargin` at its default value of `1.8em`.

To add some space *before* the footnote marker, patch `\@makefntext` using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{\llap}{\quad\llap}{}{}
\makeatother
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2em}
\setlength{\textheight}{5\baselineskip}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
Content.\footnote{Footnote}
\end{document}
```

The above patch inserts `\quad` (or, technically, `\hskip1em\relax`) before the first `\llap` - used to place the marker after measuring its width.